# Can we create an mocked service of an Graphql api in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service-virtualization

Hi i am new to graphql i want to create an mocked api that uses graphql api can someone tell me how can i do it in spring boot or by any other framework.

I tried searching for it i found there is mockprovider for js but didnt find any info for how to mock it in java.

Comment: can you specify if you are trying to mock some graphql api or trying to call some outside graphql api from your code?

Comment: i want to mock an graphql api

Comment: As far as I know there is no mock graphql solution out of the box for java. Easiest way imo would be to use any of available mocking libraries and create response object yourself.